# AddEVentListener not working on created Element

Tags: javascript

I am looping through an array and appending the items in the array to an li i created using a function in JS.

i want to add a doubleCLick eventListener to console.log the li values but for some reason the event listener refused to work. below is my code.

```js
Array.forEach((item) => {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.className =
      'list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center';
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    clipList.appendChild(button);

    let deleteLink = document.createElement('span');
    deleteLink.className = 'mx-2 text-danger';
    deleteLink.innerHTML = 'x';
    button.appendChild(deleteLink);
  });
  
  
  
  //My event listener
  const clipButton = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');

if (clipButton) {
  clipButton.addEventListener(
    'dbClick',
    (copyClip = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: To listen for double click events, use `dblclick` not `dbClick`

Comment: Additionally, there are multiple `.list-group-item` elements in the DOM, you're adding the listener to the first occurence only. Attach the event to the button inside the loop: `button.addEventListener('dblclick', ....);`.